# How to install oracle 12c with odbc driver

Tags: odbc, oracle12c

I want to configure oracle 12c to work with odbc, but not able to install odbc driver for odbc clients. Can you please let me know how to install obdc drivers for oracle 12c
Not able to get 12c odbc drivers for windows 7

---

Answer (score 1):

I know it's ultra late, but I'm recently setting up ODBC on Server2012 using Oracle's ODBC driver.  Turns out that the Oracle ODBC driver is a separate download you extract to your ORACLE_HOME and 'install'.